# How can I remove tab from the toolbar of primeng p-editor in angular 8?

Tags: angular, editor, primeng, quill

This is m code. tabIndex ="-1" works for most of them but it doesnot work with select tag and with "ql-image". I want to remove all the tab from them and want the focus to be directly in editor box instead of tools.

```
 <p-editor #editor required [(ngModel)]="comment.comment" name="comment"  class="pEditor"
        [style]="{ height: '180px', 'font-size': '1.2em' }">

        <p-header>

          <span class="ql-formats">
            <select class="ql-header" tabindex="-1">
              <option value="1" tabindex="-1">Heading</option>
              <option value="2" tabindex="-1">Subheading</option>
              <option selected tabindex="-1">Normal</option>
            </select>
            <select class="ql-font" tabindex="-1">
              <option selected tabindex="-1">Sans Serif</option>
              <option value="serif" tabindex="-1">Serif</option>
              <option value="monospace" tabindex="-1">Monospace</option>
            </select>
          </span>
          <span class="ql-formats">
            <button class="ql-bold" aria-label="Bold" tabindex="-1"></button>
            <button class="ql-italic" aria-label="Italic" tabindex="-1"></button>
            <button class="ql-underline" aria-label="Underline" tabindex="-1"></button>
          </span>
          <span class="ql-formats">
            <select class="ql-color" tabindex="2"></select>
            <select class="ql-background" tabindex="2"></select>
          </span>
          <span class="ql-formats">
            <button class="ql-list" value="ordered" aria-label="Ordered List" tabindex="-1"></button>
            <button class="ql-list" value="bullet" aria-label="Unordered List" tabindex="-1"></button>
            <select class="ql-align">
              <option selected tabindex="-1"></option>
              <option value="center" tabindex="-1"></option>
              <option value="right" tabindex="-1"></option>
              <option value="justify" tabindex="-1"></option>
            </select>
          </span>
          <span class="ql-formats">
            <button class="ql-link" aria-label="Insert Link" tabindex="-1"></button>
            <button class="ql-image" aria-label="Insert Image" tabindex="-1"></button>
            <button class="ql-code-block" aria-label="Insert Code Block" tabindex="-1"></button>
          </span>
          <span class="ql-formats">
            <button class="ql-clean" aria-label="Remove Styles" tabindex="-1"></button>
          </span>
        </p-header> 
      </p-editor>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You had almost achieved this but added tabindex="-1" on wrong place in select box.

```
 <select class="ql-header" tabindex="-1">
```

```html
<p-editor #editor required name="comment" class="pEditor" [style]="{ height: '180px', 'font-size': '1.2em' }">

  <p-header>

    <span class="ql-formats">
            <select class="ql-header" tabindex="-1">
              <option value="1" tabindex="-1">Heading</option>
              <option value="2" tabindex="-1">Subheading</option>
              <option selected tabindex="-1">Normal</option>
            </select>
            <select class="ql-font" tabindex="-1">
              <option selected tabindex="-1">Sans Serif</option>
              <option value="serif" tabindex="-1">Serif</option>
              <option value="monospace" tabindex="-1">Monospace</option>
            </select>
          </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
            <button class="ql-bold" aria-label="Bold" tabindex="-1"></button>
            <button class="ql-italic" aria-label="Italic" tabindex="-1"></button>
            <button class="ql-underline" aria-label="Underline" tabindex="-1"></button>
          </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
            <select class="ql-color" tabindex="-1"></select>
            <select class="ql-background" tabindex="-1"></select>
          </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
            <button class="ql-list" value="ordered" aria-label="Ordered List" tabindex="-1"></button>
            <button class="ql-list" value="bullet" aria-label="Unordered List" tabindex="-1"></button>
            <select class="ql-align" tabindex="-1">
              <option selected tabindex="-1"></option>
              <option value="center" tabindex="-1"></option>
              <option value="right" tabindex="-1"></option>
              <option value="justify" tabindex="-1"></option>
            </select>
          </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
            <button class="ql-link" aria-label="Insert Link" tabindex="-1"></button>
            <button class="ql-image" aria-label="Insert Image" tabindex="-1"></button>
            <button class="ql-code-block" aria-label="Insert Code Block" tabindex="-1"></button>
          </span>
    <span class="ql-formats">
            <button class="ql-clean" aria-label="Remove Styles" tabindex="-1"></button>
          </span>
  </p-header>
</p-editor>
```

Update 1

primeng doesn't remove tabindex from selected span.

You have to remove this in your ngAfterViewInit method

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const spans = document.getElementsByClassName('ql-picker-label');
  for (let i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].removeAttribute('tabindex');
  }
}
```

Here is stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-ktq7va).

Comment: I tried removing tabindex="-1" as well as b y adding from select. It is not working though.                              
 <select class="ql-header" tabindex="-1">                                                                              <select class="ql-header" >

Comment: Missed use case. updated and added stackblitz link too

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in angular 9.

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
     const test = this.pEditor.el.nativeElement;
     const elements = test.querySelectorAll('.ql-picker-label');
     for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
     elements[i].removeAttribute('tabindex');
    }
  }
```